# 2-3 trees segmentation fault on search/deletion

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement 2-3 trees and I get a segmentation fault when searching for the node to be deleted. Here's the code:

```
p = root;
while (p!=NULL || p->k1!=kkey || p->k2!=kkey)
{
     if (kkey < p->k1)
        p = p->st;
     else if (kkey > p->k1 && kkey < p->k2)
        p = p->mid;
     else
        p = p->dr;
}
```

So I'm trying to search for the node that contains the kkey. The debugger tells me I have a Segmentation fault in that while where I'm trying to check whether the key was found or we are still in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` condition looks highly suspect.

Let's say `p` is `NULL`; the `while` will still try to dereference `p->k1` and will segfault.

Did you mean to say `&&` ("and") instead of `||` ("or")?